# python dictionary first value

Tags: python

the following code save in a dictionary the object candle by timestamp. i have had a problem with the initialisation and i get the following output

```
class CandleBuffer:
    def __init__(self,candle=None):
        self.candlebuffer={0: candle}
    def update(self,candle):
        #print candlebuffer
        self.candlebuffer[candle.ref_timestamp]= candle
        #print self.candlebuffer[candle.ref_timestamp].last_price
        #print candle.last_price
        for matel in self.candlebuffer:
            print matel


candleBuffer = CandleBuffer()
```

output

```
0
2013-04-04 15:38:00
```

Would you know i can get rid of that zero "first" value?

Comment: It's there because `0` is a key in your dictionary. This quesiton is really unclear. Do you just want to not print the key `0` if it is there?

Comment: Aside: from looking at your previous questions, it looks like you're writing a framework to handle OHLC time series.  If you're looking only to learn Python, then that's a fine test application, and good luck.  OTOH if you're actually interested in the results, and not in the learning experience, you're far better off using an existing library like [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) to serve as the framework.  (Your resampling question from before becomes trivial, for example.)  Depends entirely on your goal, of course.

Comment: yes i heard about panda however i need to catch up with Python first... i dont handle data analysis yet, just creating a random walk and play with the data really on the fly...

Answer (score 3):

In `__init__` set

```
self.candlebuffer = {}
```

I don't see the reason to put a value you don't want

Comment: Thanks, that looks simple but that was it! that code allows to print all the keys but i am struggling to print the value as candle is actually an object with last_price for instance as caracteristic. Can you please help me to get the correct syntax to loop on the value "last_price"?

Comment: isn't it "for aCandle in self.candlebuffer: print aCandle.last_price" ?

Comment: apparently not, but will find out, i think i need to get more knowledge around dictionary syntax...

Comment: sorry, I was in a "javascript mindset". You can't reference a key like that in Python. It's aCandle["last_price"] (I can't edit my previous comment)